# How to run an infinite thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to run a Thread infinitely, but it's not working ...

Follow the code:

```
namespace BTCPrice
{
    public static class Price
    {
        private static volatile bool _shouldStop = false;

        public static void RequestStop()
        {
            _shouldStop = true;
        }

        public static void Refresh(out string value, int tipo = 0, string source = "https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/")
        {
            while (_shouldStop == false)
            {

                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

                WebClient cliente = new WebClient();

                string json = cliente.DownloadString(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", source, "BTC", "ticker"));

                JObject j = JObject.Parse(json);

                switch (tipo)
                {
                    //Get High Price
                    case 0:
                        value = j["ticker"]["high"].ToString();
                        break;

                    //Get Low Price
                    case 1:
                        value = j["ticker"]["low"].ToString();
                        break;

                    default:
                        value = "default";
                        break;

                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            value = "Stopped";
        }
    }
}
```

On Start:

```
string result = "";
Thread workerThread = new Thread(() => {
    Price.Refresh(out result);

    MessageBox.Show(result);

    Invoke(textBox1, result);

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
});
```

No exception occurs ... as long as I remove the `While (_shouldStop == false)` class the code works perfectly. However, I would like that, while the program is open, it executes the code and updates the textbox with the value that I get by the API.

result without While(_shouldStop == false) in class:

[Expected Result with While](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt109.png)

Comment: Whats the error you get?

Comment: No error, no exception ... even with the debug nothing appears

Comment: Any time you have a very long running loop with a Thread.Sleep inside of it you are usually better off using a timer instead. Also instead of using a `private static volatile bool` you should use a `CancellationToken` instead, much more reliable.

Comment: Thats because the code never leaves the while loop and is running synchronously with the rest of the Threads work. You never get to MessageBox.Show();

Comment: The problem is that your method needs to end for the textbox to be updated.  You need to invoke the UI update from within the `while` loop.  (Note that I am not recommending this approach, just telling what needs to happen in this case.)

Comment: @SamMarion But how can I do as he rode endlessly returning my expected result?

Comment: I'm not going to code it for you but i'll respond with a quick fix in the answer.

Comment: Quick and dirty: pass the textbox into the class.  A better way would be to pass in a lambda or other delegate so the class doesn't have to know about anything.

Comment: @ps2goat passing data back to the UI like that is exactly what [`IProgress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Progress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) was created for.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain why timer is better? And what about infinite loop with sleep inside ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?

Answer (score 4):

You really shouldn't be using threads these days when there are excellent alternatives that handle all of the mess for you.

I'd suggest using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka "Rx"). Just NuGet "System.Reactive", "System.Reactive.Windows.Forms" (Windows Forms), "System.Reactive.Windows.Threading" (WPF).

Then you can do this:

```
int tipo = 0;
string source = "https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/";

string url = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", source, "BTC", "ticker");

IObservable<string> feed =
    from n in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
    from json in Observable.Using<string, WebClient>(() => new WebClient(), cliente => cliente.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url).ToObservable())
    let j = JObject.Parse(json)
    let high = j["ticker"]["high"].ToString()
    let low = j["ticker"]["low"].ToString()
    select tipo == 0 ? high : (tipo == 1 ? low : "default");

IDisposable subscription =
    feed
        .ObserveOn(this); // for Windows Forms OR .ObservableOnDispatcher() for WPF
        .Subscribe(value =>
        {
            /* Do something with `value` */
        });
```

You'll now get a steady stream of the `string` value every second. A thread is started automatically and the results are automatically pasted to the UI thread.

When you want to stop the feed producing values just call `subscription.Dispose();`.

This code entirely replaces your `Price` class.

Answer (score 2):

Change your while loop in Price.Refresh to inside the thread. Have Price.Refresh return a string instead.

```
Thread workerThread = new Thread(() => {
while (true)
{ 
    String result = Price.Refresh();

    MessageBox.Show(result);

    Invoke(textBox1, result);

    Thread.Sleep(1000); 
});
```

I agree with Scott Chamberlain in that you should use a timer instead and rewrite this but this will work for you.

Comment: I'm not saying it is if I where to do this I would completely rewrite it. How ever his question wasn't about improving the code just wanted to know why it wasn't working and I offered a quick fix for why. I appreciate you taking the time to show a more sensible approach though